# Soft deletes, navigation properties in EF4 CTP5 POCO

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, code-first

Basically, I want to use soft deletes, but have the navgiation properties not show the soft deleted records. Are there any ways to intercept the navigation property queries on POCO objects in entity framework?

Very simple example:

```
 public class Product
 {
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public int? CategoryId { get; set;}
    public virtual Category Category { get; set;}
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set;}
 }    

public class Category
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set;}
}
```

I can easily insert the criteria into my repository so that it doesn't return any products where IsDeleted==true.

However, I can't see how to accomplish this for other objects that have 'soft deleted' entites in their navigation properties.

IE If I access myCategory.Products (where myCategory is a Category) it should not show any products where IsDeleted==true

I could potentially workaround this using an additional property of Category

```
public ICollection<Product> CurrentProducts
{
    get
    {
         return this.Products.Where(p=>!p.IsDeleted);
    }
}
```

But that isn't the elegant solution I'm looking for. Is there a way to 'attach' criteria to the navigation property or any better solutions for how to handle this?

Comment: Ahh now I see your problem... :)

Comment: I would say the solution you propose is the best one.  Not sure why you don't think it is elegant?  Seems pretty clean and simple to me.

Comment: Did you find a way to approach this? I am running into the same scenario and would like to know what approach you took.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe You should look at this [from another perspective](http://www.udidahan.com/2009/09/01/dont-delete-just-dont/). Might help. Certainly won't hurt. :)

Comment: +1 very interesting link although not answering the technical question at all but focusing on business

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CategoryWithNoDeletedItems : Category
{
    private ICollection<Product> _products;
    public override ICollection<Product> Products
    {
        get
        {
            return _products;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value.Any(x => x.IsDeleted))
            {
                _products = value.Where(x => !x.IsDeleted).ToArray();
            }
            else
            {
                _products = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```